# What do I get for removing a Halloween Cauldron?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Do I just get gems?

If so, how many?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You receive 75000 elixir and 5xp.

Source: I have already looted two of them.

Comment: I will try to take a screenshot next time I loot one for you if needed.

Comment: and 5 exp, note it costs 25k to remove

Comment: 30 sec removal time

Answer (score 0):

You get 75000 elixer from it (net 50000 because you need 25000 to remove it).